# Adding a counter to count the number of rows are inserted in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to do an insert statement, but I am checking if the data has been inserted before, and if so, it will not insert the row in the table.  After this is complete, I want to return the number of rows that actually were inserted.  Can anyone help with adding a counter?  I'm using `SQL Server 2012`.

My query is as follows :

```
        If NOT EXISTS (Select Id from @List where Id = cast(@IG_Id as int))
BEGIN  
       SET @Sql = 
          'INSERT INTO '+@List+' (Id,Id,LCode,CellNumber,WorkNumber,HomeNumber)
           VALUES ('''+@CId+''','''+@LId+''','''+@LCode+''','''+@MobileNumber+''','''+@BusinessNumber+''','''+ @HomeNumber+''')'
           print @Sql END
```

Comment: please post what code you done till now. are you using `insert... select...` or `insert ... values...` or `bulk insert`?

Comment: why are you creating an Dynamic SQL? if you know the structure of that table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
If NOT EXISTS (Select Id from @List where Id = cast(@IG_Id as int))
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @List (Id,Id,LCode,CellNumber,WorkNumber,HomeNumber)
    VALUES (@CId, @LId, @LCode, @MobileNumber, @BusinessNumber, @HomeNumber)
END 

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as NumberOfInsertedRows
```

actually, since you have only one list of values to insert,  `@@ROWCOUNT` can be only 0 or 1

---

edit:  to show how to insert from another table

```
INSERT INTO @List (Id,Id,LCode,CellNumber,WorkNumber,HomeNumber)
select Id,Id,LCode,CellNumber,WorkNumber,HomeNumber
from [MyDataSetTable]
where CAST([MyDataSetTable].IG_Id as int) not in (select Id from @List)

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as NumberOfInsertedRows
```

Comment: This query will be called several times, and will have many rows inserted.

Comment: how are you intending to do so? all these variables can hold one value only, are you looping using `cursor` or `while`?

Comment: Im passing a datset that will be filled prior to calling this stored proc.  I will then insert the records one at a time, until I have reached the end of the dataset.

Comment: if you have a `dataset` you don't process each row individually, but just in one `SQL INSERT`. see the edited response